# What does "close to you behind the door" mean?

Tags: lyrics, music

I love this song, it's called "Behind the Door" by Sixth Finger. I love the song, but I have no clue as to what it really means.

Here's a link to the song, just in case:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5y3OXssV34M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I listened to the song, and I googled the lyric, and as far as I can tell it means exactly what it says:  someone is nearby, with only a door separating them from you.

Comment: You're right, now it makes sense, I've been thinking of all other meanings except this one all these days! Thank you very much :)